# react-grid-layout is not displaying the layout I pass him

Tags: reactjs, react-grid-layout

I am encountering a problem with the library react-grid-layout and I don't know if it's a bug or me doing things badly. 
I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/issues/870), but the more I think about it, the less it's probable that an issue this big has gone unnoticed.
You can find a demo of what i'm experiencing [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/njjyr9oym)

## What I'm trying to do

I'd like to create a dashboard using react-grid-layout. I'm trying to implement the  [container pattern](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005) so I have a DashboardContainer component controlling the layout *via* his state and passing this layout down to a Dashboard component in the props.

## The problem I encounter

Elements are placed correctly for the initial state but when I add items, the x, y, w and h of the added element aren't correct.
It should be (5,0,2,2) for the first addition, and it ends up being placed on (0,4,1,1)
I saw that elements can be redimensionned to 1 of width and height if they don't have the correct key, but I think my keys are correct.

Example: this layout is passed to Dashboard
[layout data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUzae.png)

But this is the displayed layout (the element "new0" isn't corresponding)
[displayed layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIqpR.png)

## My code

Here is the (simplified) code of my DashboardContainer component

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";

class DashboardContainer extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    maxRows: 8,
    cols: 12
  };

  state = {
    layout: [
      { i: "key0", x: 0, y: 0, w: 2, h: 2 },
      { i: "key1", x: 2, y: 0, w: 3, h: 2 },
      { i: "key2", x: 2, y: 2, w: 2, h: 2 },
      { i: "key3", x: 8, y: 0, w: 3, h: 2 }
    ],
    newElementsCount: 0
  };

  onLayoutChange = l => {
    this.setState({ layout: l });
  };

  add = () => {
    // here we calculate where the new element should be placed
    var x = foundX, y = foundY, w = foundW, h = foundH;
    var newLayout = this.state.layout;

    newLayout.push({
      i: "new" + this.state.newElementsCount,
      x: x,
      y: y,
      w: w,
      h: h
    });

    this.setState({
      newElementsCount: this.state.newElementsCount + 1,
      layout: newLayout
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dashboard
          layout={this.state.layout}
          add={this.add}
          cols={this.props.cols}
          maxRows={this.props.maxRows}
          onLayoutChange={this.onLayoutChange}
          preventCollision={true}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const contentDiv = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(DashboardContainer), contentDiv);
```

And here the Dashboard component :

```
import React from "react";
import RGL, { WidthProvider } from "react-grid-layout";
const ReactGridLayout = WidthProvider(RGL);

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  generateDOM() {
    return this.props.layout.map(function(item) {
      return <div key={item.i}>{item.i}</div>;
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.add}>Add</button>
        <ReactGridLayout
          rowHeight={30}
          maxRows={this.props.maxRows}
          cols={this.props.cols}
          layout={this.props.layout}
          compactType={null}
          onLayoutChange={this.props.onLayoutChange}
        >
          {this.generateDOM()}
        </ReactGridLayout>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = Dashboard;
```

The full (nearly) working code can be found in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/njjyr9oym)

I'm still very new to React and RGL so any suggestions are welcome !

Thank you

Comment: If anyone encounters this problem, I used a workaround you can find [here](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/issues/870)